# Reconocimiento de Voz JavaScript Inteligencia Artificial

Tags: java, c#, inteligencia-artificial

Tengo un proceso en javascript que reconoce voz a travez del navegador Chrome usando window.webkitSpeechRecognition, este proceso lo hace demasiado bien que al compararlo con librerias de C# o algun otro leguaje no funciona tan bien como lo hace javascript.

En este punto necesito usar C# para poder completar mi proyecto, es posible ejecutar todo el codigo javascrip dentro de un projecto en C#? cabe mencionar que el proceso en C# estara levantando varios hilos haciendo los call al proceso de JavaScript, no se si esto sera un problema?.

Creen que es lo mas conveniente y conocen alguna otra alternativa?

Comment: el API de Speech recognition es accesible sólo en Chrome, Javascript simplemente delega en el navegador la tarea.

Comment: Prueba google ellos hacen librerias de speech-to-text si te hace falta. Puedea empezar por [aqui](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/)